# dvi to ps conversion problem [SOLVED: PyX graph issue]

Tags: conversion, dvips

when running dvips on a dvi (containing just a graph included via an .eps file) the generated ps file "drops" certain characters in the graph (decimal points in the labels on the axes and capital letters in the axis title). Note that the dvi correctly shows the graph in all its details.

However, and this is what puzzling me the output of the dvips command DOES NOT give any error at all. It calls all the correct fonts without any problem.

The fonts called are all CM, and dvips locates them correctly

Any ideas ? Is it possible that certain pfb files are broken without dvips noticing that ?

[Adding that the graph was generated using PyX 0.11 This turned out to be the problem as I note in the comment. a switch to PyX 0.12 solves the issue. I therefore add a PyX tag to this question.]

Here is the dvips output

This is dvips(k) 5.98 Copyright 2009 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2012.11.07:0003' -> draft2.ps



.






[1
<./pic/Fig1ext.eps>]

Comment: This could be a viewer issue; try zooming in on the postscript, or using an alternative program to look at the file. Failing that, please make the `eps` file available for download, and add an example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hi thx for your suggestion. It turned out not to be a viewer problem, but something more subtle. The graph included in the tex document, was generated using PyX (great tool!!). Apparently the version I was using had UniqueID lookup issues for the CM fonts embedded in the PostScript output of the figure, causing certain glyphs to be dropped after a dvips. A recent PyX update solved this. So everything works just fine now.

Comment: @MathiasVanwolleghem Unlike a traditional forum, we keep questions and answers separate. Please consider posting a self-answer, and moving the appropriate material from the question.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out not to be a viewer problem, but something more subtle. The graph included in the tex document, was generated using PyX 0.11 (great tool!!). Apparently the version I was using had UniqueID lookup issues for the CM fonts embedded in the PostScript output of the figure, causing certain glyphs to be dropped after a dvips. A recent PyX update (0.12) solved this. So everything works just fine now.